# Is it possible to run another spider from Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, multiprocessing

For now I have 2 spiders, what I would like to do is

1. Spider `1` goes to `url1` and if `url2` appears, call spider `2` with `url2`. Also saves the content of `url1` by using pipeline.
2. Spider `2` goes to `url2` and do something.

Due to the complexities of both spiders I would like to have them separated.

What I have tried using `scrapy crawl`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=self.testfunc())
    p.join()
    p.start()

def testfunc(self):
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    crawler.crawl(<spidername>, <arguments>)
```

It does load the settings but doesn't crawl:

```
2015-08-24 14:13:32 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-08-24 14:13:32 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, HttpAuthMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-08-24 14:13:32 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-08-24 14:13:32 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-08-24 14:13:32 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

The documentations has a example about launching from script, but what I'm trying to do is launch another spider while using `scrapy crawl` command.

edit: Full code

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor
from multiprocessing import Process
import scrapy
import os


def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())


class TestSpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test1"
    start_urls = ['http://www.google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        info('parse')
        a = MyClass()
        a.start_work()


class MyClass(object):

    def start_work(self):
        info('start_work')
        p = Process(target=self.do_work)
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def do_work(self):

        info('do_work')
        settings = get_project_settings()
        runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
        runner.crawl(TestSpider2)
        d = runner.join()
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()
        return

class TestSpider2(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "test2"
    start_urls = ['http://www.google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        info('testspider2')
        return
```

What I hope is like:

1. scrapy crawl test1
   (for example, when response.status_code is 200:)
2. in test1, call `scrapy crawl test2`

Comment: You can capture the 'response.url' and put it in if statement and do some pattern matching through regex and then If matches your criteria do this,else do that

Comment: Yup but it doesn't do the crawling.

Comment: post your whole code here

Comment: Code added. I am thinking about giving up and use `scrapyd`, call the `scrapyd` API within the spider....

Answer (score 8):

I won't go in depth  given since this question is really old but I'll go ahead drop this snippet from the official Scrappy docs....   You are very close! lol

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

And then using callbacks you can pass items between your spiders do do w.e logic functions your talking about

Comment: Hi scriptso! thanks for you answer helpful to me.  Do you know how to pass the params from one spider to other?

Comment: There is a way to get a url returned by one Spider and use it in another Spider?

Answer (score 0):

We should not run a spider from a spider.
In my understanding, you want to run a spider when other spider finish, right ?
If so, Let's use below source code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from datascraper.spiders.file1_spd import Spider1ClassName
from datascraper.spiders.file2_spd import Spider2ClassName
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Spider1ClassName)
    yield runner.crawl(Spider2ClassName)
    reactor.stop()


configure_logging()
config = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=config)
crawl()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

You could refer here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process